# Plotly ignoring y-axis title position

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plot generated via Plotly in Python. I would like to move the y-axis title, so that it ends up to be farther from the axis. I have seen that there is a title_standoff property in Plotly figure and I tried to use it, but it seems to ignore it. It enlarges the left margin as I increase the title standoff, but the title position remains unchanged. The same problem is with the y-axis title font size, that I would like to increase. Other modifications, like the y-axis range, works well.
I tried to apply the modifications in various ways:

```
cp_plot.update_yaxes(
            title_font={"size": 20},
            title_standoff=100, 
            range=[0,1])
```

```
cp_plot.update_layout(yaxis={
            'title': {
                "font": {"size": 20},
                'standoff': 100
            },
            'range': [0,1]
        })
```

```
cp_plot.update_yaxes(title={"font": {"size": 20}, "standoff": 100}, range=[0, 1])
```

Do you have any idea about the reason of this behaviour and about what should I do?

Thank you in advance for your help

edit: I add the image of a plot to show how the y axis title is misplaced, and no matter how I modify the title standoff, it's always there:

[image]

edit2: I noticed that if I show the figure with `cp_plot.show()` it is correct, but if I save it with `cp_plot.write_image(path)` then I obtain the image above, with the title misplaced. Unluckily I need to save the image, but I really don't understand this difference

Comment: Share a picture of a graph that you think is a challenge. The way to get a fast answer is to show it and the image you expect.

Comment: @r-beginners done, the y-axis title should be more on the left, without overlapping with the y-axis labels

Comment: Now that the image has been added, the issue is clear: I applied your code using the official plotly reference as an example. I applied your code using the official reference of plotly as an example, and the result is that the labels are correctly displayed away from the y-axis.

Comment: @r-beginners I verified that if I use figure.show() it correctly shows the y-axis title, but what I was doing and what I am interested in is saving the figure into a .png file via figure.write_image(path) and for some unexplainable reason the saved image is the one I attached above, with the y-axis title misplaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood why it was not working: I was editing a plotly figure generated by a library (dalex). It turned out that they were not placing the y-axis title as y-axis title, but using an annotation. Because of this it couldn't change position or font according to the y-axis title layout. Instead, removing the annotation and adding the y-axis title with the desired font-size and standoff it works perfectly.
Moreover, the fact that it previously seemed to work using figure.show() was due the fact that somehow the annotation position changed if shown or if saved, but it had nothing to do with my layout settings on the y-axis title.